# How to handle core code throwing notice on valid input?

Tags: errors, images

I have combination of valid input with native WP function throwing PHP notice. In this specific case it is image without extension with `image_resize()`.

This is usually suppressed by WP, but it still has me worried because it runs in feed and such things can explode XML to pieces.

If I can neither change core or input then what should I do? I suppose I could try to explicitly suppress error output around there.

Or should I just ignore the possibility as edge case?

Comment: Where exactly did you get an error and what does it say? It is a php notice or a wordpress error from the wp_error class?

Comment: @kaiser as described - it's PHP notice, because `image_resize()` expects image to always have extension when it parses path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `@` operator in front of a function to suppress an error message/notice/whatever. Fun as it is: Even the `image_resize()` function uses it for `chmod`. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your own error handler, that either ignores the errors or outputs them in comments in the feed. Let it depend on the "surrounding" configuration, so if `WP_DEBUG` is `false`, ignore the errors. If it is `true`, output them in XML comments at the end of the feed, so you don't start a comment when you are in the middle of a tag.

If notices are displayed this is probably because the administrator explicitly enabled them. You would not do this on a production site, so it should be expected that some output (like RSS feeds) can break.

Comment: Great idea, that I will explore some time, but accepting kaiser's answer as more practical and immediate solution to my specific issue.